# Rounding all possible numbers below 1 to the first decimal after zeros

Tags: r, rounding

I have numbers which vary significantly. From really small to  really big. I want to round them all and do not see a proper solution for me.

Usually people round to a certain number of decimals. Simply `round(x, 2)` or whatever.

My situation is different.

For instance, I have very different numbers. And numbers below 1 with multiple zeros are my biggest challenge, because I do not want them to be rounded to zero.

```
x <- c(100.56, 100.132554444123, 10044400000.2523324, 
       1.2343454555424, 0.04454443, 0.0000000000000000000000543)

lapply(x, signif)
```

It gives me

```
[[1]]
[1] 100.56

[[2]]
[1] 100.133

[[3]]
[1] 10044400000

[[4]]
[1] 1.23435

[[5]]
[1] 0.0445444

[[6]]
[1] 0.0000000000000000000000543
```

This is almost what I need. But I would like to limit numbers below 1 with some decimals. For instance, round it the the closest meaningful decimal (first non-zero number).

I also tried a couple of other options like

```
prettyNum(x)

formatC(x)
```

but they do not resolve my question.

P.S.
Sorry for confusion.
I want to round small numbers to the closest possible decimal (not sure if I explain in properly in English, sorry).

**So it should be a custom function. I will round big number with certain decimals (from 0 to 3). Something like this**

```
x <- c(100.56, 100.132554444123, 100444.2523324, 1.2343454555424, 0.04454443, 0.0000000000000000000000543)

rounded_value <- function(value) {

if (is.na(value)) return (NA)
if (value >= 100) value <- round(value,2)
if (value >= 1000) value <- round(value,0)
if (value >= 1000000) value <- round(value,3)

return (value)
}


lapply(x, rounded_value)

[[1]]
[1] 100.56

[[2]]
[1] 100.13

[[3]]
[1] 100444

[[4]]
[1] 1.234345

[[5]]
[1] 0.04454443

[[6]]
[1] 0.0000000000000000000000543
```

My problem is with two last values - 0.04454443, 0.0000000000000000000000543.
I want to round values below 1 individually. For instance, into 0.04 and 0.00000000000000000000006. Trying to find a function which will help me to do this.

**Updated. Thanks to everybody. I am trying to rewrite this function in a more intuitive way. Sorry if my initial question was not exactly you see here.**

```
rounded_value <- function(value)
{
if (is.na(value)) return (NA)

decimals <- 1
value_out <- value
while ( (value_out<-round(value,(decimals+1))) == 0 & decimals < 10) { 
decimals <- decimals + 1 }

if (value_out > 100) value_out <- round(value_out,1)
if (value_out > 1000) value_out <- round(value_out,0)

value_out <- as.numeric(value_out) 

return (value_out)
}
```

**Update 3. My best guess now is**

```
x <- c(100.56, 100.132554444123, 100444.2523324, 1.2343454555424, 0.04454443, 
0.00543)

rounded_value <- function(value) {

# if (is.na(value)) return (NA)
if (value >= 100) value <- round(value,2)
if (value >= 1000) value <- round(value,0)
if (value >= 1000000) value <- round(value,3)
while (value <= 1) value <- signif(x, 10)

return (value)
}

rounded_value(x)
```

It gives me

```
[1]    100.56    100.13 100444.25      1.23      0.04      0.01
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output for each of the numbers in your example?

Comment: do you want `signif(x,digits=1)`?

Comment: @Marius, I added an example. Values more than 100 etc are fine, but I am struggling with values below 1, because the number of zeros can be different.

Comment: Why would 0.044... round down to 0.04 but 0.0...054 round *up* to 0.0...06?

Comment: @keithpjolley, sorry, if my explanation sucks :(. I want to round to the first number after zeros all values below 1.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying 0.54 -> 0.6 but 0.44 -> 0.4. Why is one rounding up and the other down?

Comment: @keithpjolley, apologize, just tired and midnight. They both can be rounded either to the closest top or to the closest bottom. It really does not matter.

Comment: aren't these cases what `signif()` is meant for?

Comment: @PavoDive, maybe I do not know to use it properly, see my latest update of the q please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking. Maybe this will work - or get you closer?

```
R> x <- c(100.56, 100.132554444123, 10044400000.2523324, 
+        1.2343454555424, 0.04454443, 0.0000000000000000000000543)
R> ifelse(abs(x)>1, round(x), signif(x, digits=1))
[1] 1.01000e+02 1.00000e+02 1.00444e+10 1.00000e+00 4.00000e-02 5.00000e-23
```

Comment: why are you loading `plyr`  ... ?

Comment: @keithpjolley, added more specific example, hopefully.

Comment: @keithpjolley, you option give me a bunch of zeros after first four values. [1]         101.00000000000000000000000         100.00000000000000000000000 10044400000.00000000000000000000000           1.00000000000000000000000
[5]           0.04000000000000000083267           0.00000000000000000000005. I will round them specifically. Values below 1 is my challenge.

Comment: @Oleksiy At that point, you may need to convert to `character` class to get what you want... those extra digits are floating point precision problems. See the FAQ [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061) for reading on that.

Comment: `R> c(1/3, 1)` gives you `[1] 0.3333333 1.0000000`. Changing this behavior in `R` is beyond my skills.

Comment: @keithpjolley, I updated the initial question with a specific example, which I tried to rewrite with the help of signif().

Comment: I think @Gregor's suggestion to convert to character and do what you need to do as a string is the way to go. Floating points are only occasionally accurate out to the number of decimals you are wanting. `R> 0.0000000000000444 + 1 - 1` ->
`[1] 4.440892e-14`